Equivalent Martingale Measures and Densities
Definitions:

$\sigma$-martingale:
An $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued process $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, adapted and RCLL (cadlag), is a $(P-)\sigma$-martingale if there exists an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued process $M = (M_t)_{t \geq 0}$, which is a local $P$-martingale, and an integrand $\psi \in L(M)$ such that:
$$
   X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \psi_s \, dM_s, \quad \forall t \geq 0,
   $$
where:

$\psi \in L(M)$ means $\psi \in L(M^i)$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, d$,
$\psi > 0$ almost surely.


Equivalent $\sigma$-martingale measure ($E\sigma MM$):
A probability measure $Q \sim P$ on $\mathcal{F}_T$ is an equivalent $\sigma$-martingale measure for $S$ if $S$ is a $Q$-$\sigma$-martingale.

Equivalent (local) martingale measure ($E(L)MM$):
A probability measure $Q \sim P$ is an equivalent (local) martingale measure for $S$ if $S$ is a (local) martingale under $Q$.

Equivalent $\sigma$-martingale density ($E\sigma MD$):
An equivalent $\sigma$-martingale density for $S$ is a local martingale $Z > 0$, with $Z_0 = 1$, such that $ZS$ is a $P$-$\sigma$-martingale.
If $ZS$ is even a local $P$-martingale, then $Z$ is called an equivalent local martingale density ($ELMD$) for $S$.


Remark:
If $Q \sim P$ is an $E\sigma MM$ or $ELMM$ for $S$ and $Z = Z^{(Q,P)}$ is the density process of $Q$ with respect to $P$, then:

$ZS$ is a $P$-$\sigma$-martingale or $P$-local martingale (by Bayes’ rule),
$Z > 0$ is a true $P$-martingale,
$Z_0 = 1$ if and only if $Q = P$ on $\mathcal{F}_0$.

I don't get why the remark is true. I can imagine we use$$
\mathbb{E}_P[Z_t S_t] = \mathbb{E}_Q[S_t]$$ but then I can't have the result.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
